# How to grab checkboxes and put them into state?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, html-table, state

My problem is the following: I have a table, where I generate a row with a person's name, details and details2 from an object in the DB. Next to each person there is a checkbox. I need to put those on check into an object in state and remove them from there when unchecked, because I am going to send this object on submit to the server.

How and what is the best way to do that?

I tried with current.value but I am going in circles and I don't think I have the correct idea.

````
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox"/>
                                <label>
                                    data 1
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="Column 2">
                            data 2
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <a href="#">
                                Edit
                            </a>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                                Delete
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="Column 5">
                            data 3
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can have a **handleChange** function:

```
handleChange = ({ target }) => {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  value: {
    ...prevState.value,
    [target.name]: target.value
  },
}));
```

And use it on the checkboxes (be sure to name each checkbox **uniquely**):

```
<input type="checkbox" 
     ...
     name="Checkbox1"
     onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
/>
```

Initialize the state with something like this:

```
this.setState({
     value: {},
});
```

Now, in the object **value**, you have values of all those checkboxes, and that object looks something like this:

```
value = {
    Checkbox1: true,
    Checkbox2: false,
    ...
}
```

You mention removing them from the state if they are unchecked. I suggest filtering:

```
const { value } = this.state;
const trueCheckboxesKeys = value.keys().filter(valueKey => value[valueKey]);
let trueCheckboxes = {};
for(i = 0; i < trueCheckboxesKeys.Length; i++) {
    trueCheckboxes[trueCheckboxesKeys[i]] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `onChange` event handler and record `event.currentTarget.checked` as it will return true or false. I would also recommend adding some kind of identifier to the input element so you can tell which element is being checked so you can track it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar where a user checks a box and it updates state.

You'll need an event handler for the checkbox, plus componentDidUpdate to see if the checkbox value changed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { CHECKBOX_NAME } = this.state;
  if (CHECKBOX_NAME !== prevState.CHECKBOX_NAME) {
    if (CHECKBOX_NAME === true) {
      this.setState({
        // do whatever
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        // change back if necessary
      });
    }
  }
}

handleCheckboxChange = event => {
  const { checked } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    // mark box as checked in state
  });
};

...

// checkbox
<input type="checkbox" 
  checked={this.state.CHECKBOX_NAME}
  onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
/>

//
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are fetching the data you render, does it come from props or do you get it from api, but generally, provided you have the `users` array, it could look smth like this:

```
const UserList = props => {
  const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState([]);

  // Your user data here
  const userData = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "User1",
      details: {
        /*details here */
      }
    }
  ];

  // Check if user is selected
  const isUserSelected = user => !!selectedUsers.find(u => u.id === user.id);

  // Add user to selected or remove if already there
  const selectUser = user => {
    setSelectedUsers(users => {
      if (isUserSelected(user)) {
        return users.filter(u => u.id !== user.id);
      }
      return [...users, user];
    });
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {userData.map(user => (
          <tr key={user.id}>
            <td>
              <label htmlFor={`user_${user.id}`}>{user.name}</label>
              <input
                id={`user_${user.id}`}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isUserSelected(user)}
                onChange={() => selectUser(user)}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```